# Retrieval of a broadcaster's ip address in adobe ams architecture

Tags: flash, adobe

As a client, is there a possibility to retrieve the broadcaster's ip address from the corresponding adobe AMS server ?

Answer (score 1):

You can read it in the Access Logs
https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/config-admin/access-logs.html

Comment: the problem is i don't have access to these log files, as i'm just a flash player client

Comment: You can't get user IP just in Flash Player Client, you need some connection to the server: https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/ssaslr/client-class.html, or Air application